# When i try to run html code through live server it is showing server started at port 5500 but failed failed to open in browser preview

Tags: html, server, execution, live

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IobP.jpg) I am getting server started but execution failed

Answer (score 0):

Type this link link in browser while live server is started
http://127.0.0.1:5500